# How to publish a react-component with css modules that can be consumed by both, projects using ES Modules and CommonJs for css modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

For some frameworks (eg. Gatsby >= V3) the default for importing CSS modules is as ES modules like so:

```js
import { class1, class2 } from 'styles.modules.css'
// or
import * as styles from 'styles.modules.css'
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules

Other projects such as Create React App still use the default export like this:

```js
import styles from 'styles.modules.css'
```

How can I publish a react-component (that uses css modules internally) so that it can be imported and used in both scenarios without extracting the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I found is to generate the css module hashed classes and extract the stylesheet. Then import the stylesheet with the hashed classes instead of the css module stylesheet. Every bundler that is able to import css modules should also be able to deal with the extracted css file.

I am using [babel-plugin-css-modules-transform](https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/babel-plugin-css-modules-transform) for this using the following configuration:

```json
  …
  "plugins": [
    [
      "css-modules-transform",
      {
        "extractCss": {
          "dir": "./lib/",
          "relativeRoot": "./src/",
          "filename": "[path]/[name].compiled.css"
        },
        "keepImport": true,
        "importPathFormatter": "./importPathFormatter"
      }
    ]
  ]
  …
```

The `keepImport` option will keep the import but transforms it from eg. `import * as styles from 'styles.module.css'` to `import 'styles.module.css'`.
I use this option in combination with the undocumented option `importPathFormatter` to import the transformed css. CSS preprocessing eg. postCSS is done by the consuming application.

Content of `./importPathFormatter.js`:

```js
module.exports = path => path.replace(/\.css$/, '.compiled.css');
```

In the long term I want to migrate my projects to vanilla extract and use rollup/vite for bundling, but for now this is working fine.